# how to atomically create a value and storage it in hashmap when get() returns null?

Tags: android

What I want is that if a key is already in hashmap, then return it's value, otherwise create a new value , associate it with the specified key, and return it.

I found the method `compute()` in ConcurrentHashMap could solve this. Depressingly, it needs api 24.  Is there any alternative to it?

> Call requires API level 24 (current min is 16): java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap#compute

This is my first post and i'm sorry for my bad english.

```
Data data = mConcurrentHashMap.compute("c:/directory/data", new BiFunction<String, Data, Data>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(String key, Data oldValue) {
            if (oldValue != null) {
                return oldValue;
            } else {
                return new Data();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Always post code as text

Comment: ok, you can look at the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `compute` method just changes a value in the map, but does so in a more "functional" and sometimes more concise way.

Your code is basically this without any Java 8 stuff:

```
String oldValue = mConcurrentHashMap.get("c:/directory/data");
mConcurrentHashMap.put(
    "c:/directory/data",
    oldValue != null ? oldValue : new Data()
);
```

Just in case you decide to use Java 8, you can do this more concisely:

```
mConcurrentHashMap.compute("c:/directory/data", (key, oldValue) -> Optional.ofNullable(oldValue).orElse(new Data()));
```

Comment: get() and put() will execute a common query code.That's the core performance problem.

Comment: @Rao I highly doubt there is a way to do this more efficiently then using `get` and `put` with Java 7. Are you _actually_ having performance problems or are you just speculating? (never optimise prematurely!)